# Displaying error messages for a form using custom Validation - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm implementing a colour picker using custom directives and want to display an error message when the user selects all blue. Setting the error isn't a problem, however making the connection between the error message and the forms '$error' property is. I know the error is being set and that the form is becoming invalid because I can disable the button but I can't get the error message to show. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
        <form name="myForm">
            <h1>Colours</h1>
            <label>
                Foreground
                <colour-picker ng-model="mainCtrl.foreground"></colour-picker>
                <p ng-show='myForm.$error.mainCtrl.foregroundBadColour'>Too much blue</p>
            </label>
            <label>
                Background
                <colour-picker ng-model="mainCtrl.background"></colour-picker>
                <p ng-show="myForm.$error.mainCtrl.backgroundBadColour">Too much blue</p>
            </label>
            <div ng-style="{'background': mainCtrl.background, 'color': mainCtrl.foreground}" class="results">
                Results
            </div>
            <div>
                <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="mainCtrl.test">Click Me</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MainController', ['$scope',function($scope){
    var mainCtrl = this;
    mainCtrl.foreground = '#F00';
    mainCtrl.background = '#000';

    mainCtrl.test = function(){
        alert('Testing Testing');  
    };
    console.log(myForm)
}])
.directive('colourPicker',[function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attributes, ngModelController){
            console.log($attributes.ngModel);
            console.log($scope);
            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(value){
                var colours = value.split('');
                console.log(colours);
                return {
                    red: colours[1],
                    green: colours[2],
                    blue: colours[3]
                }
            });
            ngModelController.$render = function(){
                $scope.red = ngModelController.$viewValue.red;
                $scope.green = ngModelController.$viewValue.green;
                $scope.blue = ngModelController.$viewValue.blue;
            };
            $scope.$watch('red + green + blue', function(newValue, oldValue){
                ngModelController.$setViewValue({
                    red: $scope.red,
                    green: $scope.green,
                    blue: $scope.blue
                })
            });

            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(value){
                var allBlue = (value.red === '0' && value.green === '0' && value.blue === 'F');
                console.log($attributes.ngModel + 'BadColour');
                ngModelController.$setValidity($attributes.ngModel + 'BadColour', (!allBlue));
                console.log(ngModelController);
                return value;
            });

            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(value){
                return '#' + [value.red, value.green, value.blue].join('');   
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```